# As3 - A plan to make a troubleshooting multiple choice app

Tags: actionscript-3

Sorry, but I'm really a beginner.

Have you seen the kind of troubleshooting in "Help and Support" in Windows? It is like, for instance, my mouse was broken. It would ask if I had trouble with Hardware or Software, then if I choose Hardware, it would fetch the appropriate multiple choice question, for example asking me if I had problem with the screen, mouse or ...

I wanted to created a similar app with flash, but I don't know how exactly the best way to store my information.

I am bad at scripting, but I had something like this:

```
var database:Array = [
                      ["What kind of problem do you have?", ["Family", 1, 0], ["Friends ", 2, 0], ["Money", 3, 0]],
                      ["Had family violence", ["True", 1, 1], ["False", 1, 2]]
.
.
.
and so on
```

*explanation: database[0][0] is the first question. ["Family", 1, 0], Family is one of the choices, 1 and 0 was the place the next question was stored in, databse[1][0].

I know this is a very bad array, but what is a better way to store my information and get them out easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sql or xml. In your case a xml would be more simple!
read up on it here -> [AS3-XML Basics](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/)